# I think I received a tag badge when I shouldn't

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, badges

If you check my so's [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119895/macarse) you will notice that I got the Android silver badge (`Earned 400 upvotes for answers in the android tag.`).

But in the tags section it says:

```
365 android× 501
```

Why did I get the badge then?

Comment: +1 for caring more about the system than a badge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [top users listing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/topusers), you have a tag score of 403. I'm not sure what exactly accounts for the difference, as the numbers are normally synced. The top users appears to be the more accurate one, though, as you do have the badge now.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that page existed. Check that Reto Meier has 788 there and he doesn't have a silver badge. http://stackoverflow.com/users/822/reto-meier

Comment: @Macarse Now *that*, I definitely cannot explain. You'll need a dev to explain that one.

Comment: @Macarse To have a silver tag badge you need to have answered at least 80 questions for that tag. The user you have pointed too only has 63.

Comment: @status Oh, hah, I should've remembered that. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @status-completed: Great, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Grace, this is actually a bug, see my answer

Answer (score 7):

This is actually a bug I just resolved.

Our tag storage is denormalized, we have a second table that stores the a `postId` -> `tagId` list. For some reason we had a few dupes in there (probably cause android was merged with android-sdk).

That had a cascading effect that caused some tag badges to be assigned early.

I just added a primary key constraint on the denormalized table, so there is no chance of dupe rows anymore.

Comment: Huh, interesting. Well, so much for my original thought. Thanks for the update!