# Got a tag badge — but have not earned it yet

Tags: support, badges, tag-badges

This morning I got the silver [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) badge :

> [image]

...

> [image]

Unfortunately, I haven't earned this particular badge yet. I have 318 votes on 124 answers. Then wondered if [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) had synonyms, like [twitter-bootstrap-2](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-2) and so on, but this is not the case — and even if it was, I should have got the badge for some time already.

I saw this old question, back from Jan 2011 -> [I think I received a tag badge when I shouldn't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76327/197939) - the "official" statement to this old question was :

> Our tag storage is denormalized, we have a second table that stores the a postId -> tagId list. For some reason we had a few dupes in there (probably cause android was merged with android-sdk).
>
> That had a cascading effect that caused some tag badges to be assigned early.
>
> I just added a primary key constraint on the denormalized table, so there is no chance of dupe rows anymore.

This bug seems not to completely have been wiped out, perhaps it has returned — in any case, something does not seem completely right. I got an upvote on the [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) tag yesterday, forcing the system to recalculate, this is the right part.